# Changing the size of individual element in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I stretch the items inside a div to fill the area, and is it possible to have the items in different sizes without having to modify individually using `:nth-child(x)`. For instance: first, third and fifth item to be twice as big as second and fourth item?

```css
.my_class_a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class_a">
   <div class="item">a</div>
   <div class="item">b</div>
   <div class="item">c</div>
   <div class="item">d</div>
   <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

I do apologize because I don't know how to format in fiddle way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I stretch the items inside a div to fill the area...

Use the `flex-grow` property.

> and is it possible to have the items in different sizes without having to modify individually using :nth-child(x).

How is the browser supposed to know what you want if you don't define the behavior?

> For instance: first, third and fifth item to be twice as big as second and fourth item?

In this case, you can use the `even` and `odd` functions of the `nth-child()` pseudo class.

```css
.my_class_a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: lightgreen; /* for demo only */
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange; /* for demo only */
}

/* for aligning item content */
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class_a">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: very very helpful, didn't knew at all about this pseudo class "odd" and "even".

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `flex-grow: 1;` to allow flex items to become larger. (Note that i defined a width for the container, otherwise they won't grow)

Concerning your wish about the 2nd, 4th etc. item: You need to define * somewhere*  which items should grow and which not, so you you need at least *some*  kind of selector for them.

```css
.my_class_a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class_a">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c<br>c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

P.S.: To create a snippet (the "fiddle-line" code example, just click the 7th symbol in the toolbar of the answer window)

Comment: How to center the inner div, of class item such that it will be always centered both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: That wasn't your question (which i already answered...), but: Either use `text-align: content` (if it's only text) or you need to use a seperate div inside the flex-items, which you center using one of the usual methods for centering. Vertical centering can be achieved using `align-items: center`on the flex parent. (see also the code in my edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex` style declaration - it's a shorthand for:

`flex-grow` | `flex-shrink` | `flex-basis`

where `flex-basis` is the initial width of the flexbox child and `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` determine how quickly the flexbox child will grow or shrink relative to its siblings.

For instance:

an element with `flex: 2 2 100px` starts with a width of `100px` and will grow or shrink twice as fast as `flex: 1 1 50px` which starts with a width of `50px`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.my_class_a {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
align-items: center;
}

.item {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

.item-a,
.item-c,
.item-e {
flex: 2 2 100px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); 
}

.item-b,
.item-d {
flex: 1 1 50px;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class_a">
   <div class="item item-a">a</div>
   <div class="item item-b">b</div>
   <div class="item item-c">c</div>
   <div class="item item-d">d</div>
   <div class="item item-e">e</div>
</div>
```